How to have TS trust me when I use the `as` operator?
I have the following code and TS has issues with the conversion using the as keyword.

Conversion of type 'FileList' to type 'File' may be a mistake because
neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was
intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Here is the code:
   async uploadButtonHandler(event) {
      try {
         var files:FileList[] = await this.browseForFile(".png,.jpg") as Array<FileList>;
         
         if (files) {
            var file = files[0] as File; // error here
            var filename = file.name;
            var binaryBuffer = new Blob([file.buffer]); // error here (buffer not found)
            console.log(files);
         }
      }
      catch(error) {
         console.log(error)
      }
   }

Is there an option to turn this off when using the as operator?
Example on TS playground

If files is a FileList[], wouldn't files[0] be a FileList, not a File?

HTMLInputElement files returns FileList | null, so why not make your promise typesafe?

And there's so many things wrong here. FileList is already an array (iterator). File already conforms to Blob

"Is there an option to turn this off when using the as operator?": No, TS will not allow you to directly cast a type to another type that has no structural compatibility overlap.

@jsejcksn I thought that as keyword was a way to override code intelligences? It is saying, "Try to convert whatever this object is into this other type. Trust me" It seems like TS defeats the purpose of the as keyword.

The as operator is intended to support widening/upcasts (generally safe) and narrowing/downcasts (generally unsafe), not completely arbitrary changes/"side"casts.  If you want to do one of those, do as unknown as or as never as or anything you want that converts the single sidecast into an upcast/downcast pair.

@jcalz I posted the code on typescript playground (link above) and it shows multiple casting / type errors there. no matter what I try to return TS has problems with it. The only thing that works is Promise<unknown> and then that has problems too.

I'm not sure what to say there. It's clear your code has lots of problems, but these problems probably shouldn't be solved with type assertions unless you're positive what you're doing is safe. Surely files[0] is a FileList and not a File, and yes, you can force a type assertion to work there, but why? Type assertions are a last resort, and it's clear from this code you haven't gotten there yet. Fix your code first, I guess? But that's not what you're asking with the question. The question is "how can I get TS to trust me with as" and the answer is as unknown as.

UPDATED ANSWER:
Ok, I've just seen your TS playground code, the problem is that you are not typing your browseForFile method properly.
You need to type the inner promise to FileList | null so it doesn't return unknown. Here's a quick (simplified) example of your code:
browseForFile(acceptedTypes: string, allowMultipleFiles = false): Promise<FileList | null> {
   // here we're specifying that this promise will resolve to a FileList or null:
   return new Promise<FileList | null>((resolve) => {
      const element = document.createElement("input");
      element.type = "file";
      if (acceptedTypes) element.accept = acceptedTypes;
      element.multiple = allowMultipleFiles;
      element.addEventListener("change", (event: Event) =>
         resolve((event.target as HTMLInputElement).files), { once: true });
      element.addEventListener("cancel", () => resolve(null), { once: true });
      element.click();
   });
}

and this is how to use it:
// no need to cast anything else here anymore
const files: FileList | null = await this.browseForFile(".png,.jpeg");

if (files?.length) {
  const file: File = files[0];
  ...
}

---- OLD
If it's an array of File objects, shouldn't it just be:
const files: File[] = (await this.browseForFile(".png,.jpeg")) as File[];

if (files?.length) {
  const file: File = files[0];
  ...
}



hmmm... it should be... did you see the example code? I might be doing something incorrect in the browseForFile() call.

ok, I've updated the answer based on what I saw in your TS Playground, take a look and see if that's what you need. Hope it helps.

Thanks! I had struggled with promises on this one. I didn't know you could put the entire code inside the promise. The errors went away but haven't had a chance to test it yet.

Is the suggestion in the error not enough?
     var files:FileList[] = await this.browseForFile(".png,.jpeg") 
         as unknown as Array<FileList>;

But some suggestions:

try to not do this.  browseForFile is returning something that is not a FileList array.  Lying to the compiler will just cause errors at run-time
var should never be used in Typescript.  It is there strictly for backwards compatibility (with very, very old code).


The method browseForFile() returns a Promise<unknown>. I tried to have it return other values and it has errors.

I've added the code to Typescript Playground link above

In the code browseForFile() returns Promise<unknown>. The example code is used to show the additional errors

@1.21gigawatts: you wrote that code!  Here is a version with some of the more egregious errors fixed up.

Thank you for the example. I know I wrote that code. I was posting it so you could see what is going on and see if you had any ideas. To me, if I have to cast to unknown then that tells me that maybe the code in my function is incorrect. Another answer and yours shows that to be true.

I'm going to continue to use var. There is nothing wrong with it. I know how it works and I know why it works. I also use const when it's appropriate. I rarely use let because there are weird rules around it that tooling has had issues with. I'm actively disagreeing so that others don't argue with me in the future about using var. It's ok to use var.

@1.21gigawatts — I can’t stop you using from using var but there are lots of things wrong with it and it’s not ok to use.  const is almost always appropriate.  Once in a long while, let is preferable.
